# How can i fix my enemy movement, and collision?

Tags: java, collision-resolution

I recently started a project with some friends, Its a simple java game and im having issue getting the Collision and enemy movement working properly.

Using this:

```
if(tempObject.getId() == ID.Block) {
            if (getBoundsBig().intersects(tempObject.getBounds())) {
                velX = -velX;
                velY = -velY;
            }
            else {
                velX = (jenny.nextInt(4 - -4) + -4);
                velY = (jenny.nextInt(4 - -4) + -4);
            }
        }
```

I can get basic enemy movement, however the collision doesn't seem to work. Enemies often change velocity really fast but the enemies end up phasing through walls. I thought just setting the velocity to the negative counterpart would be enough. Its not.

[image: In - Game footage of enemy phasing]

As seen in the gif above the enemy still decides to run right through a wall. Any ideas on how i could fix this?

Comment: We have dozens of questions here asking "my collision routine doesn't work, how can I fix it?" - so you might find working solutions available out of the box in those answers. Try searching through the [tag:collision-resolution] tag for questions similar to yours and check out how those users solved their problems.

Comment: Why `nextInt`? Enemies in your animation do jitter even when not colliding with a wall, then this piece of code is being called continuously. The new random velocity should be set after a collision has occurred, and not at all times.